# Why is the zero set of $T$ equal to the zero set of the ideal generated by $T$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I don't understand the last part of the first paragraph

> Clearly, if $\mathfrak{a}$ is the ideal... common zeros of the finite set of polynomials $f_1,\ldots,f_r$.

I don't quite understand how an ideal generated by a set implies that their zero sets are equal. Also, I don't see why an ideal has finitely many generators if the ring is noetherian.

> [image]

Comment: Please make your question titles more informative in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $T\subseteq\mathfrak{a}$, clearly $Z(\mathfrak{a})\subseteq Z(T)$.  On the other hand, if $P\in Z(T)$, that means $f(P)=0$ for all $f\in T$.  For any $P\in Z(T)$, the set $I=\{f\in A:f(P)=0\}$ is an ideal, and so since it contains $T$, it must contain $\mathfrak{a}$.  Thus $P\in Z(\mathfrak{a})$.  Since $P\in Z(T)$ was arbitrary, this shows $Z(T)\subseteq Z(\mathfrak{a})$, so they are equal.

As for your second question, I can't answer without knowing what your definition of "Noetherian" is.  Quite often, a ring is *defined* to be Noetherian if every ideal is finitely generated.

Comment: I am also new to Hartshorne and I am wondering if I can prove $Z(T)\subset Z(\langle T\rangle)$ as follows: let $P\in Z(T)$, then $f(P)=0$ for all $f\in T$. Let $g\in\langle T\rangle$, then by definition $g$ can be written as $$g=a_{1}f_{1}+a_{2}f_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}f_{n}$$ for some $a_{1},\cdots, a_{n}\in k[x_{1},\cdots, x_{n}]$, some $f_{1},\cdots, f_{n}\in T$ and for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, it is clear that $$g(P)=a_{1}(P)f_{1}(P)+a_{2}(P)f_{2}(P)+\cdots+a_{n}(P)f_{n}(P)=\underbrace{a_{1}(P)0+a_{2}(P)0+\cdots+a_{n}(P)0}_{f_{i}(P)=0\ \text{for all}\ i}=0,$$

Comment: and therefore $P$ is a zero of $g$. As $g$ was arbitrary, $P$ is in fact a common zero of every element in $\langle T\rangle$, and thus $P\in Z(\langle T\rangle).$

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying!!